# How can you determine installed versions of the glibc libraries?

Tags: linux, gcc, gnu, cross-compiling

I'm working with an embedded Linux deployment and am using a cross compiler tool chain that doesn't compile I2C library function calls.

**How do I determine the precise versions of the libraries on the system so that I may rebuild the tool chain?**

I don't intend to replace the libraries deployed, as I do know they work (including I2C), so I believe I need the following:

- Binutils version
- GCC version
- GLIBC
- Kernel (for the headers)

I think I can assume from the following that the binutils library is version 2.2.5. The kernel is modded for which I've the source.

```
root@dev-box />ls /lib/ -al
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root     1024 Apr 27 09:44 .
drwxrwxrwx 14 root root     1024 Jan  1  1970 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   105379 Jan  1  1970 ld-2.2.5.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       16 Jan  1  1970 ld-linux.so.2 -> /lib/ld-2.2.5.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       16 Jan  1  1970 ld.so.1 -> /lib/ld-2.2.5.so
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  1288601 Jan  1  1970 libc.so.6
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    25441 Jan  1  1970 libcrypt.so.1
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    14303 Jan  1  1970 libdl.so.2
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    36800 Jan  1  1970 libgcc_s.so.1
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root   530401 Jan  1  1970 libm.so.6
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    86626 Jan  1  1970 libnsl.so.1
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    17533 Jan  1  1970 libnss_dns.so.2
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    46324 Jan  1  1970 libnss_files.so.2
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    98633 Jan  1  1970 libpthread.so.0
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    69966 Jan  1  1970 libresolv.so.2
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    12897 Jan  1  1970 libutil.so.1
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For glibc:

`/lib/libc.so.6`

Sounds maybe strange to run a so file but should print out version information in this case

For the kernel version use `uname`

For the binutils parsing the output of `ld --version`might yield what you expect, the same for `gcc --version`. This is a bit tedious but I do not know another way.

Comment: Since I know the kernel's version I didn't try `uname`, on my system it didn't work.  Instead `version` gives me love.

Comment: How can a library also be an executable?

Comment: this is out of date because of newer multiarch layouts.

Comment: @Amias Not out of date on my Ubuntu 18.04 installation, although the library has gone up a few version in the last 8 years.

Comment: On My CentOS 7 install, `locate libc.so` returns `/usr/lib64/libc.so.6`.  (It's a symbolic link to `libc-2.17.so`.)

Answer (score 5):

a more comprehensive answer can be found by running

```
find /lib -iname 'libc*.so'
```

On a recent system this will give you results like this that show i'm using glibc 2.28 here on ubuntu 18.10

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.28.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.28.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.28.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.28.so
```

For multiarch system you can have multiple copies for 386 and 64 modes , i think these should be the same .

i didn't have a /lib/libc.so.* on my system.

Answer (score 4):

To know the current installed version of glibc, please compile and run the following C code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gnu/libc-version.h>
int main (void) { puts (gnu_get_libc_version ()); return 0; }
```

Cheers !!!

Comment: On Fedora 29, `/lib64/libc.so.6 --version` prints *`GNU C Library (GNU libc) stable release version 2.28`*.

Comment: Also, on Debian 11, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 --version` prints the version as `GNU C Library (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.35-0ubuntu3.6) stable release version 2.35`, whose version number matches the output of the compiled code above.